# Language/User Rankings?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I know users already have a reputation score, but what about the languages they use? For example, what if I'm interested to see of all the [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) questions out there, which users and/or languages come out on top (which get the most accepted or highest-voted answers)?

Perhaps this could include organization by all tags overall, not just the challenge type. Possibly also expanded to be listed by user, i.e. UserX has 14 answers using Perl, 10 using Python, etc.

I think this may require the ability to tag answers, but I can see other ways of aggregating.

Does anyone else see this as an interesting/useful feature? I think based on my perception of use, it would really be meant for the codegolf.SE site, but who knows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that the system collects this data right now--it would after all require parsing answers to do it. And no data means no rankings...

Comment: Exactly, hence my idea of tagging answers. Is this something anyone else would be interested in seeing?

Comment: While perhaps not quite in keeping with the usual SE user ranking system I think that having language, question and problem statistics on a per user basis would be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

This is unlikely to happen on the site (via some builtin functionality). However, [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/1416601/top-language-golfers?Lang=Python) is an SEDE query which lists the top users for a given language, plus some more interesting statistics (average score per answers, answering tenure, etc.)

Additionally, you can navigate to any tag and click the "Top users" link to be taken to the [top users in that tag](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/topusers), sorting by total net score, for both asking and answering. You might have to do some manual searching/collating to get more advanced information